# Proxy Filtering with Squid

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, amazon-ec2, squid

I am currently faced with a situation where i would like to deploy a proxy server on amazon EC2 running on Ubuntu.

What i am trying to achieve is to have Wifi users in each site have their traffic filtered by this Server. On the proxy server itself i would be simply blacklisting all URLs with the exception of 2 specific URLs.

This proxy server is to serve requests from about 7 of such sites

My Network Diagram for each site is as below :

INTERNET <- VPN ROUTER <- WIFI Network ( 192.168.9.0/24) - Wifi Clients
                        <- Private Network ( 192.168.10.0/24)

I have implemented squid proxy servers before however the way I used to implement them is like so :

Private Network -> Proxy Server -> Firewall -> Internet

However due to some budget constraints and the temporary nature of this setup i don't plan to deploy a proxy server in each of the sites.

Just a bit of background info, the Wi-fi router is just a basic home / office router that has pretty limited functionality and the VPN router is pretty standard off the shelf with limited features.

I am just not sure if my approach is going to work, I would like to hear if my plan is actually workable or any other alternatives (low cost) of how i can achieve this.

Comment: No reason why this shouldn't work, apart from how easy it might be for users to not use your proxy. It might be better to use openwrt on your wifi router and implement some filtering / forwarding there.

Comment: This will depend heavily on the capability of the VPN router, but correctly configured to *tunnel* all internal traffic to the proxy, yes, it should work.

Comment: @wurtel, thanks i tried openwrt and it works great, however as squid or most proxy filtering solutions have issues filtering https type URLs, i resorted to whitelisting specific addresses instead.